# Variable was not declared in this scope

Tags: arduino-uno

When I compile this code I get a  error: 'currentState' was not declared in this scope.

The code:

```
enum state: int
 {
  NOTREADY,
  WAITSTARTUP,
  WAITSECRET,
  REVEALSECRET
 }

state currentState; <---- Error

const int BUTTONPIN = 4;
const int ROTARYPIN = A0;

void setup() 
{
  //Open Serial Monitor for debugging purposes
  Serial.begin(9600);

  //Configure the pins
  pinMode(BUTTONPIN, INPUT);
  pinMode(ROTARYPIN, INPUT);

  //Initialise the LCD
  lcd.begin(16, 2);

  //Assume that the current state is wait for start up signal

  currentState=WAITSTARTUP;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have missing semicolon after the enum:

```
enum state: int
 {
  NOTREADY,
  WAITSTARTUP,
  WAITSECRET,
  REVEALSECRET
 };  // <-- here
```

Answer (score 0):

//go the Tools > Boards and check that you have selected the right option of your hardware? your remaining code is almost ok. But remember to add semicolon ";" sign at end every coding line.

```
  enum state: int{NOTREADY,WAITSTARTUP,WAITSECRET,REVEALSECRET};      
  state currentState; //<---- Error

  const int BUTTONPIN = 4;
  const int ROTARYPIN = A0;

  void setup() 
  {
    //Open Serial Monitor for debugging purposes
    Serial.begin(9600);

    //Configure the pins
    pinMode(BUTTONPIN, INPUT);
    pinMode(ROTARYPIN, INPUT);

    //Initialise the LCD
    lcd.begin(16, 2);

    //Assume that the current state is wait for start up signal

    currentState=WAITSTARTUP;
  }
```

Comment: I don't see what has board selection to do with this problem. And the solution to the actual problem was already posted.